# ¿por qué no puedo cambiar el formato fecha en r?

Tags: r

Tengo un archivo .csv que tiene datos extraidos con la app Science Journal de google. Los datos tienen información sobre sonidos tomados en una fecha puntual. Esta fecha viene normalmente en una cantidad numerica no fechada, así.

> > ```
> >  df_sonido <- read.csv(file = "Experimento sin t_tulo Grabaci_n 1.csv")
> >
> > names(df_sonido) <- c("Tiempo", "Sonido")
> > ```

con el output:

> > ```
> > ## Tiempo Luz
> > ## 1  1.55068e+12  92
> > ## 2  1.55068e+12  92
> > ## 3  1.55068e+12  92
> > ## 4  1.55068e+12  92
> > ## 5  1.55068e+12  92
> > ## 6  1.55068e+12  92
> > ## 7  1.55068e+12  92
> > ## 8  1.55068e+12  92
> > ## 9  1.55068e+12  92
> > ## 10 1.55068e+12  92
> > ```

para convertirlo he tenido la siguiente solución

> > ```
> >   df_sonido$Tiempo <- as.POSIXct(df_sonido$Tiempo/1000, origin = "1970-01-01")
> > ```

la cual he obtenido de internet, pero cuando la aplico al código me aparece el siguiente error:

> > ```
> >  Error in Ops.POSIXt(df_sonido$Tiempo, 1000) : '/' not defined for "POSIXt" objects
> > ```

lo cual me genera dudas puesto que he visto que al dividir por mil en los ejemplos que leí queda perfectamente acomodada la fecha.

¿existe otra forma de solucionar el error o hay algo en el código que pueda mejorar?

Comment: El error no es consistente con el código, fíjate que se está mencionando otra variable `dia1.1$Tiempo`. Por otro lado el error en sí, lo que dice, es que no existe la división para un dato `POSIXt`. Lo que se me ocurre es que tienes un error tipográfico, y estas haciendo algo así `as.POSIXct(dia1.1$Tiempo)/1000` o directamente `dia1.1$Tiempo` ya es un `POSIXct`

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que indicas, hacer la división por mil (`1000`) es a efecto de tener los datos acordes al [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

En ese sentido, vas por la dirección correcta, porque se quiere convertir un número a fecha.

Por tanto, se requiere la función `as.POSIXlt` para que el número dividido por mil, sea tratado como numérico, luego se obtiene el formato `ISO 8601` respectivo, pero como se quiere `YYYY-MM-DD` se puede emplear también `as.Date`.

Finalmente el código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
df_sonido$Tiempo <-as.Date(
                        as.POSIXlt(
                            df_sonido$Tiempo/1000,
                            origin = "1970-01-01",
                            tz="GMT") # o el tiempo de zona que se emplee
                        )
df_sonido
       Tiempo Sonido
1  2019-02-20     92
2  2019-02-20     92
3  2019-02-20     92
4  2019-02-20     92
5  2019-02-20     92
6  2019-02-20     92
7  2019-02-20     92
8  2019-02-20     92
9  2019-02-20     92
10 2019-02-20     92
```

En este caso todo los datos son iguales, porque la data proporcionada en la pregunta, está con notación científica (se omite información con ceros), no obstante esto debe trabajar correctamente con sus datos:

```
df_sonido <- read.table(header = T, text = "
                    Tiempo Sonido
                    1.55068e+12  92
                    1.55068e+12  92
                    1.55068e+12  92
                    1.55068e+12  92
                    1.55068e+12  92
                    1.55068e+12  92
                    1.55068e+12  92
                    1.55068e+12  92
                    1.55068e+12  92
                    1.55068e+12  92")

cat(format(df_sonido$Tiempo, scientific = FALSE), sep="\n")
1550680000000
1550680000000
1550680000000
1550680000000
1550680000000
1550680000000
1550680000000
1550680000000
1550680000000
1550680000000
```

Sólo quiero añadir que las fechas como son números, se manejan con una longitud de diez dígitos [Date-time Conversion Functions](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html) por eso se divide `e+12/e+3` para obtener `e+9`

```
as.POSIXlt(1472562988, origin = "1970-01-01", tz="GMT") 
as.POSIXlt(1.472562988e+9, origin = "1970-01-01", tz="GMT") # notacion cientifica
# "2016-08-30 13:16:28 GMT"
```

Porque trabajar con números más grandes nos llevarían a fechas bastante alejadas de la actual, no hay nada misterioso detrás de la división del mil (`1000`).